# vues js pass object on redirect

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have two components: **projectListComponent** and **projectSingleComponent**.
I would like to pass object on redirect from component 1 two 2.
My code is:

**projectListComponent.vue**

```
<template>
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" v-for="(item, index) in projects" :key="item.id">
            <div class="card" v-if="percentCompletedTask(index) != '100%'">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" :style="{width:percentCompletedTask(index)}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{percentCompletedTask(index)}}</div>
                    </div>
                    </h6>
                    <p class="card-text">{{item.description}}</p>
                    <router-link :to="{ name: 'projectSingleComponent', params: {id: item.id, project: item} }">Read More</router-link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template
<script>
import projectSingleComponent from '@/components/projectSingleComponent.vue'

    export default {  
        name: 'projectListComponent',     
        data() {
            return {
                components: {projectSingleComponent},
                newProject:
                    {
                        title: '',
                        description: '',
                        status: false,
                        task:[]
                    },
                projects:[
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        title: 'ptyxiakh',
                        description: 'TEI',
                        status: false,
                        task:[{title:'task1', completed: false}, {title:'task2', completed: true},{title:'task2', completed: true}]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        title: 'vue app',
                        description: 'My first vue js app',
                        status: false,
                        task:[{title:'task1', completed: false}]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        title: 'Codeigniter',
                        description: 'My first codeigniter app',
                        status: false,
                        task:[{title:'task1', completed: false}, {title:'task2', completed: true}]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        title: 'Codeigniter_new',
                        description: 'My first codeigniter app',
                        status: false,
                        task:[{title:'task1', completed: true}, {title:'task2', completed: true}]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        title: 'nexctloud',
                        description: 'My first codeigniter app',
                        status: false,
                        task:[{title:'task1', completed: true}, {title:'task2', completed: true},{title:'task2', completed: true}]
                    },
                    
                ],
                completedProject:[],
                uncompletedProject:[]
            }
        },
        
        }
    }
    

</script>
```

**projectSingleComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Id: {{project.id}}</h2>
        <h2>title: {{project.title}}</h2>
        <h2>description: {{project.description}}</h2>
        <h2>status: {{project.status}}</h2>


       
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'projectSingleComponent',  
        data() {
            return {
                project: {
                    id: 0,
                    title: '',
                    description: '',
                    status: false,
                    tasks: []
                }
                
            }

        },
        created() {
            let projectData = this.$route.params;
            alert(projectData)
            
            
        }  
    };
</script>
```

my app alert me this message "[object Object]". How parse my data from array projects(projectListComponent) to second component?

Answer (score 0):

When you alert or print an object JS tries to turn it into a string so that's why it's printing "[object Object]". Obviously this isn't very useful, but you should be able to alert(projectData.id) or alert(projectData.project), as those are the actual individual params that you passed.

Comment: i have try projectData.project to display my data but i have not successful display. again display [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use console.log(projectData) instead of alert, when you work with objects. It will be easier to get around and figure out how to access object properties.

Comment: again display [object Object]